# Explanation of a function definition in logic gate code in Problems in Data Structures and Algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, boolean-logic

(I am new to Python and OOP so please let me know if I use nonsensical language at any point.)

The book [Problems in Data Structures and Algorithms](https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html) implements code for binary and unary logic gates in a hierarchical fashion. Please see the bottom of my question for the full relevant code.

My particular query is: in the Connector class, in the constructor, there is the line

```
tgate.setNextPin(self)
```

Referring back to the unary gate where the setNextPin function is defined:

```
def setNextPin(self,source):
    if self.pin == None:
        self.pin = source
    else:
        print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")
```

The "source" in the function setNextPin is the input of the function setNextPin. So when I see the line tgate.setNextPin(self),  it tells me to go back to the unary class (tgate) to find the function setNextPin, and that the input ("source") of the setNextPin function is self, which in this case is an instance of the Connector class. However, I don't really see how this makes sense. I don't see how a connector class could be the input for the variable "source" in setNextPin.

The full code:

```
class LogicGate:

    def __init__(self,n):
        self.name = n
        self.output = None

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output

class UnaryGate(LogicGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)

        self.pin = None

    def getPin(self):
        if self.pin == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin input for gate "+self.getName()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pin.getFrom().getOutput()

    def setNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pin == None:
            self.pin = source
        else:
            print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")


class NotGate(UnaryGate):

    def __init__(self,n):
        UnaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):
        if self.getPin():
            return 0
        else:
            return 1


class Connector:

    def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
        self.fromgate = fgate
        self.togate = tgate

        tgate.setNextPin(self)

    def getFrom(self):
        return self.fromgate

    def getTo(self):
        return self.togate
```

Comment: Why can't a `Connector` be the source? `UnaryGate` does `self.pin.getFrom()`, and `Connector` has a `getFrom()` method.

Comment: The source of a pin is a connector, and the connector connects that pin to the output pin of some other gate.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for response. So is this right: we have a data object called connector, and we can set the pin (which is supposed to be an input in a logic gate) equal to that connector? I did not expect the input of a logic gate to be the connector itself.

Comment: @Barmar oh I understand now what you mean, especially with the fact that we are calling getFrom which is a function of the connector class. Thanks!

Comment: Think of the `Connector` class as representing the wires that connect all the logic element.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your time, I totally get it now. If you wanted to just copy paste what you wrote into an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Connector` class represents the wires that are used to connect logic gates to each other. `setNextPin()` is given a `Connector`, and associates this with the `pin` property. When it wants to get the logic gate that provides its input, it calls `self.pin.getFrom()`, which goes to the `Connector` `getFrom()` method, which then returns the `Connector`'s `fromgate` property, which will be the gate at the other end of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

First we should note that `setNextPin(self,source)` is a method of `binaryGate` class as well `unaryGate`.

In the function definition `setNextPin(self,source)`, `self` is `tgate(alias of a Gate class)` and `source` is the instance of Connector class. Suppose `aaa-->bbb` (`a` is connected to `b`) then the  connector will be a alias of object bbb's PIN and connector attribute .`fromGate` will a alias to previous link that is `aaa`.